# Syntax Error in Update Statement in my code

Tags: vb.net

good day, i have the following codes:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim compDate As Date
    Dim x As New Integer
    Dim profID As New Integer
    Dim date1 As New Date
    compDate = Format(Date.Now, "hh:mm:ss, tt")
    'MsgBox(compDate)
    date1 = #8:00:00 AM#
    profID = 201400001
    x = 1
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    cmd.Connection = cnn
    'Timer1.Start()
    Timer1.Interval = 5000
    sp.Close()
    Try
        sp.Open()
    Catch
        sp.Close()
    End Try
    If TextBox1.Text = "201400001" Then
        If DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, date1, Date.Now) > 5 Then
            MsgBox("been here")
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE test " & _
                              "SET ProfLog" & x & "" & _
                              "WHERE ProfID='" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "' AND ProfTime=#" & date1 & "#"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Did this")
        End If
        MsgBox("Done!")
    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "201400002" Then
        MsgBox("Hello World Again!")
    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "201400003" Then
        MsgBox("My Turn!")
    End If
    TextBox1.Clear()
End Sub
```

once it reach the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery, a syntax error is being displayed. it says that there is a "Syntax error in UPDATE statement" i would like to know what is the syntax that makes my program go wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: doesn't look like you have an = sign after your set proflog column

Comment: SQL INJECTION WARNING - this code is subject to attack via SQL Injection.  Instead of building your statement via string concatenation, consider using a parameterized query.  Then build a parameter collection and execute the query with that.  Much safer.

Comment: Microsoft is a large corporation, not a programming language. If you want help here, you need to use the proper tags so that people that can help you see the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your UPDATE statement. You're missing an `=` after `SET ProfLog`:

```
"UPDATE test " & _
    "SET ProfLog = " & x & "" & _
    "WHERE ProfID='" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "' AND ProfTime=#" & date1 & "#"
```

You could have figured this out yourself by showing the `cmd.CommandText` in a message box or the immediate window in Visual Studio.

Please do yourself a **huge favor** and search for "parameterized queries" or "SQL injection". You should learn to do things properly from the start, instead of learning to do them poorly and causing yourself many, many problems later.